# Is there a way to create a formula where I can change the variable but keep all other constant? Including the total amount

Tags: excel-formula

I need to create a pricing model where the TCO (the total amount) remains the same). Inside I have 3 or 4 different variables. I want to be able to change one of the variable of the calculation, keep the total the same and have the other variables change accordingly so the total remains the same.

- Case 1: 1+2+3=6
- Case 2: 2+1+3=6 (here I have changed variable 1 from 1 to 2 and the other have changed also.

Comment: This cannot be done with a formula. It will require vba

Comment: @ScottCraner thanks for the message, any hints for that?